# How much is he keen not to do something when he’s saying “I do never – if I can help it”?

Tags: adverbs, expressions, negation

I guess ‘if I can help it’ is a kind of ‘if possible’. It seems *help* means to prevent or avoid.

By the way, how much are the speakers keen not to do something in the following  sentences?　I can’t figure out why *never* (not in any circumstances) and *if I can help it* are compatible.

1. (*Harry Potter 3* [US Version]: p.226)[Bold font is mine]

   > I **never** wear those socks **if I can help it** ….
2. (from Google search)[Bold font is mine]

   > And stuff on the list I will **never EVER** eat **if I can help it**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase "if I can help it" can be generally thought of as equivalent with "if possible", but there are some important distinctions. "If I can help it" is ultimately less forceful, meaning that the person is less dedicated to avoiding something.

For instance, a true vegetarian would never say, "I never eat meat if I can help it." The latter implies that there are situations in which the person feels obliged to eat meat (when Mom's cooking, when visiting a foreign country, etc.). A strict vegetarian, however, would deny such a situation exists (in everyday life, at least - the desert island question is another story).

The use of "if I can help it" shows us that the speaker believes that his/her influence over a given situation is limited. Someone willing to accept that is someone who is less than fully bound to their belief or desire. There are those who hold to something so strongly that they believe, barring perhaps threat of death, that they can *always* "help it".

In short, the user of the phrase "if I can help it" has a decided opinion but is not an ideologue.

Comment: The word ‘limited’ gave me a flash of understanding. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you have answered your own question, Totoro. ‘If I can help it’ means ‘if it is in my power to influence the course of events’. There is no incompatibility with ‘never’.

Answer (score 2):

"*If I can help it*" softens the outright rejection, and turns it into a strong preference. It isn't as strong as saying "*I will never*."

The person saying this strongly doesn't want to do it, but if it becomes necessary, she will do it.